# How to get default page url in liferay?

Tags: liferay

I set default page URL in portal-ext.properties.

> default.landing.page.path=/group/guest/home

Then create portlet with Controller :

```
public class UserPortrait extends MVCPortlet {


@Override
public void render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) {

}

@Override
public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

    super.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);
}
```

}

Now , how to get landing page URL in processAction method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply, use `com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil.get(String propertyName)` to get any property from portal-ext.properties file.